# Not able to access objects inside the response from subscribe

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular8

- List item

I am not able to access the object key value pair inside subscribe method. It says  Cannot read property 'cash' of undefined at SafeSubscriber._next (tab1.page.ts:27. Let me share my code

my service.ts file

```
  private liveData=new BehaviorSubject(0);

  getappData(){
     this.file.readAsText(this.file.dataDirectory, "kdata").then(fdata => {
      this.authToken=fdata;
      return this.http.get('http://kairav.rapidesk.in/api/live_rate/',{},{'Content-Type': 'application/json','Authorization': "Token" + " " +  this.authToken})
      .then(data=>{
       this.test=JSON.parse(data.data).results;
       console.log(this.test);
       this.liveData.next(this.test);

      })
    });
  }

 getLiveData(): any{
    return this.liveData.getValue();

  }

  getLiveDataObservable(): Observable<any>{
    return this.liveData.asObservable();

  }
```

My .ts file where I have subscribed

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.loginServiceService.getappData();
    this.loginServiceService.getLiveDataObservable().subscribe((res: any) =>{
      console.log(res);
       this.test=res[0].cash;
      console.log(this.test;
    })
  }
```

Here is the response I am getting from subscribe
[image]

[image]

Comment: What's the console log output?

Comment: It say 'cash' is undefined  at SafeSubscriber._next at line this.test=res[0].cash; of my component file

Comment: I'm talking about `console.log(res)`

Comment: I am getting my correct object. I have added the output of console.log(res) image in my question

Comment: Are you sure that log is from getappData() and not from getLiveDataObservable() subscription?

Comment: yes @FedericoProvenziani. When it reaches the console of test it breaks giving the error I mentioned above

Comment: You are trying `res[0].cash` but the initial data might be `0` from the default value of the observable. Try to replace `new BehaviorSubject(0)` with `new Subject()`. `BehaviorSubject`s can hold values and emit them at subscription.

Comment: What if you move the line `this.loginServiceService.getappData()` after the subscribe call?

Comment: @raviShah upload your issue in stackbliz as its very hard to identify the issue when you say your response is getting log, but you are unable to fetch data from that array or object

Comment: Too many logs imho, is easy getting confused.

Comment: @MichaelD Thanks a lot, it worked. I replaced new BehaviorSubject(0) with new Subject()

Comment: @RaviShah If you want to use behaviour subject then you can try using `new BehaviorSubject([ ]);`

Comment: That worked too, Thanks @Adityatoke

Comment: @RaviShah You can upvote the comment which worked for you as it will help others if they came across similar issue